# Does a while loop is required inside readable event for Node.js streams?

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, eventemitter

Event: Readable

> The 'readable' event is emitted when there is data available to be
>   read from the stream

Method: Read

> The readable.read() method pulls some data out of the internal buffer
>   and returns it

About the `size` argument

> If the size argument is not specified, all of the data contained in
>   the internal buffer will be returned.

An example from the Node.js' docs

```
const readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.on('readable', () => {
  var chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read())) {
    console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
  }
});
```

If the `readable` event is fired when we have a new data to be read and we used the `read` method without specifying the size why they use while loop here since as per my understanding the `read` gets all the data ?